# Windows 7 Full Control Directories

Tags: logging, windows-7, permissions

Is there a standard common directory under Windows 7 to which all users have Full Control access to write data?  We have an application under Win 7 that runs on special workstations which needs to write logfiles for debugging.  The app is written in Java and uses logback to log.

I am tearing my hair out over not being in control of anything on these workstations.  We ask that Full Control be granted to all users for our logfile directory, and maybe they do, maybe they don't but then "Policy" gets applied and the application can't write/delete/rename logfiles as it needs to.  I have been around the block over and over on this.

I am not worried about malicious activity.  Group policy ALREADY prevents the user from using Windows Explorer, Office, command line, IE or anything other than our application.  They can't do anything not under our program's control.  But I can't get to a situation where I know that the logging will always behave the way I want it to.  If one person logs onto the machine and then someone else does, questions of file "ownership" get in the way of the program doing what it needs to do.

So my question is there a directory which - by default - is always open to whatever user happens to be logged in - to run a program that writes, deletes, and renames files regardless of which user created them originally?

**UPDATE: (in response to Remy Lebeau's answer)**

Remy, in a comment below, points me toward what I was looking for. However, there are two issues with that.

1. I said our application was written in Java and as such, as far as I know, does not have access to the APIs mentioned in his links, so we would be restricted, as far as I know, to hardcoding a path such as C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data. This is not a show-stopper but less than ideal.
2. More significantly, I have tried this and it doesn't work in my case. In cmd window I can cd into this directory, and apparently copy files into it. (copy command says it succeeded, but then a dir command doesn't show it), and I, a user on my own PC with admin rights, cannot view the directory in Windows Explorer.  About this, two questions arise:

   a. What is up with this odd windows behavior in which actions for which user apparently lacks rights to execute (say, for example, a file copy) sometimes appear to succeed (proceed without visible error) and yet the operation does NOT actually complete.

   b. Are all these problems the result of my corporation having a more restrictive group policy than "normal" which prevents these Microsoft-documented directories from functioning as documented?  How can I view the group policy so that I might intelligently request some relief from the people who administer these policies?

Comment: 1) you can use JNI to access native APIs from Java code. 2a) when UAC is enabled, file system virtualization is likely redirecting the files to another location that the user does have rights to access. 2b) probably not. This is standard for Windows, especially in recent years as default security policies gets tighter and tighter, even for admin users.

Comment: @Remy_Lebeau: So is what you are calling "UAC" and I am calling "group policy" different names for the same thing?

Comment: No, they are different features. UAC (User Account Control) is a new security subsystem introduced in Windows Vista (see  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648649.aspx). It includes changes to what type of security tokens are given to users when they log in, which in turn affects how users access secure objects, including files and the Registry. Even admin users do not have full admin rights anymore, they have to be prompted for permission if a process needs to do something that requires high privileges.

Comment: Policies, on the other hand, are customizable rules that admins can tweak as desired (including turning UAC off). That has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share the files between multiple user accounts, then create a subfolder under the [`CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) folder ([`FOLDERID_ProgramData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Vista+), and manipulate your files inside that subfolder as needed.

If you need to work with files only for the current logged in user, then create a subfolder under the [`CSIDL_APPDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Roaming) or [`CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (non-Roaming) folder (or [`FOLDERID_RoamingAppData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`FOLDERID_LocalAppData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Vista+), and manipulate your files in that subfolder as needed.

You can use [`SHGetFolderPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or related function (or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Vista+) to retrieve the actual path of such special folders, as their default locations differ from one OS version to another, and they can be further customized by users via Registry edits.

Comment: Thanks, Remy, this is very helpful and sort of what I was looking for.  But note that I said our application was written in Java and as such, as far as I know, does not have access to these APIs so we would be restricted, as far as I know, from hardcoding a path such as C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data.  I have tried this.  In cmd window I can cd into this directory, and apparently copy files into it.  (copy command says it succeeded), but then a dir command doesn't show it, and I, a user on my own PC with admin rights, cannot view the directory in Windows Explorer.

Comment: @SteveCohen: You can use JNI to access native APIs from Java code. Also look into Windows's filesystem virtualization when UAC is enabled, that might account for the missing files.